# failure of al_draw_line() in ALLEGRO

Tags: c++, c, allegro, allegro5

When I want to draw a line by using `al_draw_line(100,100,400,400,al_map_rgb(255,255,0),5);`, my `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY` gets closed automatically  and statements after this line does not execute. My program just halts

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
int main(){
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display=NULL;
    if(!al_init()){
        return -1;
    }
    if(!al_init_primitives_addon()){
        return -1;
    }
    display=al_create_display(600,600);
    al_draw_line(100,100,400,400,al_map_rgb(0,0,0),3);
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(20.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you show us some more code?

Comment: Did you build Allegro yourself? If not, maybe the binary package is incompatible with your compiler. The above code should not crash, unless the display is not created, but that shouldn't ever happen (unless you have a very tiny screen <600x600).

Comment: i am using dev c++.i am successfully create display and able to create timer but al_draw_line fail each time

Comment: Did you build Allegro yourself? If using Dev-C++, you are probably using gcc. If you downloaded a pre-built version of Allegro, then it must match your gcc version exactly. If not, expect crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't check for the return value of `al_create_display`, that can fail. Anyway: I don't know why your program apparently crashes (your code doesn't do anything that should crash, aside from not checking the display) but you won't see anything because you:

- A) draw the line and background in the same color (black)
- B) clear the background color *after* drawing the line (thus overdrawing it).

Your code after making some changes:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display=NULL;
    if(!al_init()){
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't initialize allegro!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(!al_init_primitives_addon()){
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't initialize primitives addon!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    display=al_create_display(600,600);
    if(!display) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't create allegro display!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_draw_line(100,100,400,400,al_map_rgb(255,0,0),3);
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(1.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

If it's actually your display that's broken, you should at least get an error message now. This works for me though, and I don't see why it shouldn't for you (unless you try to create this in fullscreen mode, which won't work).

Comment: sir i have added this line but my allegro display crash automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
al_draw_line(100,100,400,400,al_map_rgb(0,0,0),3);
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
```

These two lines are backwards.  You're clearing (wiping) your display AFTER you are drawing your line.  So you are never actually seeing the line.